# TestContainers - create GenericContainer and get the uri/path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I'am trying to create isolated test env using **TestContainers** (for database - postgresql and external services - for example authorising service). My question is, how can i set path in `application.yml`/`application.properties` to these external services? With db is easy i just need to use `"jdbc:tc:postgresql:14.5:///dbtests"`, to create containers with my services i use `GenericContainer<?>` and ports are different every start. TestContainers (except db) are initialized in external class.

Comment: Are you using spring boot? See the Spring Boot example https://www.testcontainers.org/examples/ and check @DynamicPropertySource https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/DynamicPropertySource.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have to think about how you can inject the dynamic connections URLs into your system-under-test. How you can do is very specific to your application. If you create objects yourself, you can simply to construction dependency injection, like in [this example](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/examples/redis-backed-cache/src/test/java/RedisBackedCacheTest.java#L28).

For frameworks, there is generally a framework-specific approach. As Eddú already mentioned in the comments, Spring-Boot allows the usage of [`DynamicPropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/DynamicPropertySource.html).